# Why isn't my new PC displaying font icons?

Tags: windows-7, windows, browser, fonts, icons

Quite simply, I just cannot see what should be font icons on lots of websites, regardless of if I use Firefox, Chrome, or IE. Here is a screenshot of what I see when I visit icomoon.io

I cleared the whole cache (everything from all time) in Firefox but it's still not displaying them. They did work in Chrome when I cleared the cache there though. They also don't show up in IE9 either after clearing that cache.

In Firefox, under Tools -> Content -> Fonts -> Advanced, I have the option checked for "Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of my settings above". Is there anything else in Firefox that I should check?

[image]

Comment: Try clearing your browser caches and see if the fonts load...

Comment: I cleared everything from all time in Firefox but it's still not displaying them. They did work in Chrome when I cleared the cache there though. They also don't show up in IE9 either after clearing that cache.

Comment: Both IE and Firefox have settings to ignore webpage-specified fonts. Have you checked those?

Comment: In Firefox, under Tools -> Content -> Fonts -> Advanced, I have the option checked for "Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of my settings above". Is there anything else in Firefox that I should check?

Comment: Yeah, that Firefox setting and the about:config for downloading fonts are both enabled. I am confused here.

Comment: What is PC ? Laptop? Tower?

Comment: PC tower, windows 7